# How can I get working visa of UK or US countries?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I am from India. I want to go UK or USA based on work permit. 
Currently I am working in IT company as a Android Developer.
And My relatives is in UK and USA. They have now green card. How can I go there? 
 Please guide me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this question is off-topic (more suitable for the expats site), let me answer it anyway:

The standard way to work abroad is to apply for jobs in the country that you want to move to. If you get the job (and your future employer is ok with jumping through the hoops needed to get you to the UK or US), they will give you documentation that you can use for *applying* for a working visa. Note that there may be limits on the number of working visa of certain types issued every year, and you may still be denied a visa even with the proper documentation.

By the way: why didn't you ask your relatives?

Comment: I already asked my relatives they are also said to me as your answer.

Comment: How they can help me?

Comment: They can help you by providing more detailed information about the process once you have a suitable job offer.